# Change video play speed dynamically

Tags: html, video, setinterval, timing, event-listener

this is my first post and I am very new to HTML, so please excuse if this question might seem dumb to you. This is how the code is supposed to work: Play a movie. Every 1,5 seconds slow the speed of the movie down by 20%. Whenever the user clicks the mouse increase the speed by 20%. This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<video id="my-video" src="big_buck_bunny.mp4"></video>

<script>
  document.getElementById("my-video").play();
  var speed = 1

  document.addEventListener ('click', speedUp, false);

  function speedUp(){
  if (speed < 1){
    speed = speed + 0.2;
  }
  document.getElementById("my-video").playbackRate = speed;
}

window.setInterval(speedDown(){
    if (speed > 0){
    speed = speed - 0.2;
  }
  document.getElementById("my-video").playbackRate = speed;
}, 1500);
</script>
```

When I start it, it just shows the first frame of the movie and stops there. Chrome throws an error in line 18 (window.sentInterval[...]) but I cannot figure out what it is. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because this line:

```
window.setInterval(speedDown(){
```

should be:

```
window.setInterval(function speedDown() {
```

(where the `speedDown` name is optional in this context).

Comment: Works just as I want it to! Thanks a lot!